# SSRS - using a row value for individual fields

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a section of a SSRS2005 report that must display 6 identifiers in two rows of three
i.e.

Val1, val2, val3

val4, val5, val6

The dataset for these fields will have up to 6 rows.

I want the identifier from row 1 to go in val1, identifier from row 2 to go in val2, etc up to val6

I'm having a brain dead day as I can't figure out how I can do this, can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal table perhaps?

Think this is a duplicate question btw.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/ten-common-sql-server-reporting-services-challenges-and-solutions/